# How to display data from a SQLite DB using PHP v.5.6.24?

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to get out data of a SQLite Database and display this data on my website. I am using PHP version 5.6.24 (and I have not the permission to update it).

From [this](https://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php) PHP Manual I took the following code:

`

```
$db = new SQLite3('DB_NAME.db');

$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM user');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    var_dump($row);
}`
```

and I got this output:

> array(10) { [0]=> NULL ["Username"]=> NULL [1](https://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php)=> NULL ["FirstName"]=>
>   NULL [2]=> NULL ["LastName"]=> NULL [3]=> NULL ["Authorithy"]=> NULL
>   [4]=> NULL ["ProfilePicture"]=> NULL }

The Attributes of my db are Username, Firstname, ProfilePicture and Authorithy but I want to get the data from the table and not only the header attributes.

How to write such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That result indicates there is one row in the `user` table, and all the column values are NULL.